# How to fix DIM error in jaccard distance?

Tags: octave, distance-matrix

I am trying to create a Jaccard distance from the Y. I do not know even if is correct what I am coding. I took an error message about DIM...i have checked on the internet but I cannot figure out. Maybe my code in total is wrong

```
Y=[1,0; 1,1; 1,0]
m = 1 - [(sum(min((Y-Y(1, :)), (Y-Y(2, :)), (Y-Y(3, :))), 3))/(sum(max(Y-Y(1, :)), (Y-Y(2, :)), (Y-Y(3, :)), 3))]
```

I expect a 3x3 matrix but i receive an error

error: min: DIM must be a valid dimension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me how what you're trying to do here (a Jaccard distance requires two inputs, not clear what your inputs are), but in any case you have syntactical errors here.

To begin with, you've got imbalanced brackets in your 'max' function (presumably it should be `max((Y-Y(1,:)), ...` rather than `max(Y-Y(1,:))` (notice the single opening bracket) which ends the function call. The fact that you're using a lot of superfluous brackets and bad indentation / spacing style makes it even harder to spot these. E.g. a better way to write this (purely visually) might be:

```
m = 1 - [ sum( min( Y - Y(1,:),         ...
                    Y - Y(2,:),         ...
                    Y - Y(3,:) ), 3 )   ...
          /                             ...
          sum( max( Y - Y(1,:),         ...
                    Y - Y(2,:),         ...
                    Y - Y(3,:) ), 3 )   ...
        ];
```

Or, better yet, capture the intermediate results into meaningfully named intermediate variables, so that your code reads like english and is easier to follow and debug, i.e.

```
VectorOfMinima = min( Y - Y(1,:), Y - Y(2,:), Y - Y(3,:) );
VectorOfMaxima = max( Y - Y(1,:), Y - Y(2,:), Y - Y(3,:) );

SumOfMinima = sum( VectorOfMinima, 3);
SumOfMaxima = sum( VectorOfMaxima, 3);

Jaccard = 1 - ( SumOfMinima / SumOfMaxima );
```

Having said all that, your use of `min` and `max` is wrong though. I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve, but effectively `min` (and `max` respectively) can only be used in the form `min(X, [], DIM)` which determines along which dimension to obtain minima in for the matrix `X`, or `min(X, Y)` which returns a new matrix with the minimum of either X or Y at each position. You're effectively calling `min` as `min(X, Y, Z)` which is not a valid call for `min`.